# offset screen on a laptop (screen changed)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

hello i have change my notebook's screen ,whitch was the same model and fit perfectly , and it worked perfectry until today (48 h of clean service ).

In facts the ploblem is tha it should be recognized as a 1024 600 but now is by 780 .

result : got an bit of invisible screen "under plastics"

If i reduce the resolutio to its normal value {1024 600] i only obtain a black srtip on top or a strech [if  i use center or strech in the intel driver opt°)

an other thing is that the bios now use that wrong definition !!

My question is where i can get a software who can adjust the stretch of my news spooky definition 
or where is the file tha i have to modify ,setting the real syze of my screen ??

acer aspire one happy2

Comment: Have you tried to confirm all cable connections?  This sounds like a hardware issue rather then a software issue to be honest

Comment: it works for a few day ,i dont thnik its logicaly possible .

Comment: What was the reason the original screen failed?

Comment: it finally appear that my video chip was slowly dying ....